# PM2 log output limits

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2

I'm happy with how PM2 formats and outputs the log with

```
pm2 logs app
```

But currently it truncates the log to 20 last entries:

> [PM2] Tailing last 20 lines for [app] process
>   ...

Is there a way to change the limits and output it in a similar manner, but with 1000 lines, for example?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try this

```
pm2 logs 'YOUR_PROCESS' --lines 1000
```

Comment: Great. Is there a way to force this behaviour by default with pm2 config file?

Comment: I think no. But you can check their documentation.

Comment: Didn't find anything on that, adding `lines` to config couldn't help as well. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @CharithJayasanka logs are stored in some files, you just can read the file content

Comment: is there a way to continually listen or read logs, instead of me executing this command again and again?

Comment: When you run this command it  is streaming the logs.

Answer (score 3):

```
pm2 logs 'process_name' --lines 500
```